# Add + infront of every word of given sentence in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I think this problem can be done with regex. But unfortunately I am not good in regex. I have a sentence now I want to add '+' in front of every word.

Example: **Input:** I have a pen
**Output will be:** +I +have +a +pen

I have found some solutions but these don't solve my problem. I have tried with the below way. But it gives me output like this:
`I+have+a+pen+` but I want `+I +have +a +pen`

```
  $('.addCharacter').click(function(event) {
      var textareaInput=$('.textareaInput').val();
      var strToArr=textareaInput.split(' ');
      var arrUniqueVal=arrUnique(strToArr);

      $('.textareaInput').val(arrUniqueVal.join('+'));
      console.log(arrUniqueVal);
      //alert("ok");
   });
```

N.B: I want to be able to input multiple sentences.

**Update: Input:**

```
hello world one  
hello world two  
hello world three
```

**Output:**

```
+hello +world +one  
+hello +world +two  
+hello +world +three
```

Comment: Why not `"+" + sentence.split(" ").join(" +")`?

Comment: try this     var str = " I have a pen";
str = str.replace(/\s+/g, ' +')

Comment: @navnit: If you change that to `str = str.replace(/(^|\s+)/g, "$1+");`, it'd make a very good answer (rather than comment). Much better than my answer. I suggest posting it.

Comment: thanks for your suggesstion @T.J. Crowder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regular expression: `/(^|\s+)/g`, which says to match either the beginning of the string (`^`) or (`|`) a series of whitespace characters (`\s+`). The `()` around it makes it a *capture group*. Then you use `replace` with the replacement string `"$1+"`: `$1` means "put the content of the capture group here" and `+` is a literal `+` character. The `g` on the regular expression means "global" (e.g,. throughout the entire string):

```js
var str = "I have a pen";
str = str.replace(/(^|\s+)/g, "$1+");
console.log(str);
```

The advantage to using `\s` (whitespace) is that you don't have to worry about what a "word character" is, so it works well even in languages that have different "word characters" than the English ones JavaScript defines. For example, Norwegian:

```js
var str = "Jeg bor i Østlandet distriktet";
str = str.replace(/(^|\s+)/g, "$1+");
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
str = str.replace(/\b\w/g, "+");
```

Above regexp will match start of a word and add '+' to it.